# woomark infinite gallery clashing with bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the GBKS woodmark jquery infinite gallery plugin with JADE and EXPRESS.

I am also using bootstrap css, there is apparently a clash with bootstrap.css that makes the absolute positioning used by woomark fail onload.

The main issue is that the absolute positioning of li in a ul by bootstrap is over-writing the absolute positioning of li in a ul of the woomark gallery plugin.

There is a temporary solution of just calling the method again to re-position the site a couple of milliseconds after the site loads, but I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: OK, And what problem you have?

Comment: My problem is that if you use bootstrap css, the tiles don't get set in an onload. You can check out the effect in zipco.cc where I am staging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't a clash with bootstrap, it's that wookmark doesn't know the height of the images before loading them. In order to fix it:

1. Add the Images Loaded JS plugin - https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded
2. Modify the wookmark code so that it doesn't trigger before all the images are loaded:

   ```
   <!-- Once the images are loaded, initalize the Wookmark plug-in. -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#tiles').imagesLoaded(function() {
     // Prepare layout options.
     var options = {
       autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
       container: $('#main'), // Optional, used for some extra CSS styling
       offset: 2, // Optional, the distance between grid items
       itemWidth: 210 // Optional, the width of a grid item
     };

     // Get a reference to your grid items.
     var handler = $('#tiles li');

     // Call the layout function.
     handler.wookmark(options);

     // Capture clicks on grid items.
     handler.click(function(){
       // Randomize the height of the clicked item.
       var newHeight = $('img', this).height() + Math.round(Math.random()*300+30);
       $(this).css('height', newHeight+'px');

       // Update the layout.
       handler.wookmark();
     });
   });
   ```